# Disable rubber band scroll in uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

Is there a way to turn off the table view's tendency to rubber band back to the top when you are done scrolling? I'm sure it is something simple, but the UITableView class reference doesn't show any obvious property that would control this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tableView.bounces = NO;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces

Comment: worked, but created new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763660/disabling-bounces-in-uitableview-also-disables-scrolling-on-ios-5-but-not-ios4

Answer (score 0):

Just set the [bounces property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces) to NO